# How to import inner classes without path dependency in Scala?

Tags: scala, scope, inner-classes, path-dependent-type

**TL&DR:** Is it possible to (locally?) disable path-dependent typing? I'd like to issue a single import statement similar to `import x._`, but to make `C` refer to `X#C` rather than `x.C` (`X` being the type of `x`)?

I have a bunch of types:

```
class Button[M] { ... }
class Label[M] { ... }
...
```

And I happen to use them together passing the same type argument to all of them:

```
class UseSite[M] (
   btn1 : Button[M]
 , btn2 : Button[M]
 , lbl1 : Label[M]) {
  ...
}
```

I thought that it'd be nice to package all those types up so that I only need to pass the type parameter once:

```
class Swing[M] {
  class Button { ... }
  class Label { ...}
}
```

Then on the use site I'd like to be able to do this:

```
class WithSwing[M] {
  val swing = new Swing[M]
  import swing._
  class UseSite(
     btn1 : Button
   , btn2 : Button
   , lbl1 : Label) {
    ...
  }
}
```

However, this does not work properly because of path-dependent typing: `Button` refers to `swing.Button` instead of `Swing[M]#Button` so the external code has a very hard time passing the correct arguments to the `UseSite` constructor.

Is there a nice way to make `Button` refer to `Swing[M]#Button` rather than to `swing.Button`?

Comment: Will renaming "val swing" to something else (to eliminate import ambiguity) work?

Comment: Why not avoid this problem altogether by putting the classes inside an object instead of another class?

Comment: Daniel, because objects can't have parameters.

Comment: Rogach, I guess not. I don't know what ambiguity you are talking about.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the path dependencies really are accidental, then rather than chase type projections all the way through your codebase, you could try something like this,

```
class Button[M]
class Label[M]

trait Swing[M] {
  type ButtonM = Button[M]
  type LabelM = Label[M]
}

class WithSwing[M] {
  val swing = new Swing[M] {}
  import swing._
  class UseSite(btn1 : ButtonM, btn2 : ButtonM, lbl1 : LabelM)
}
```

Outside `WithSwing` usage would look like,

```
val ws = new WithSwing[String]
import ws.swing._
new ws.UseSite(new ButtonM {}, new ButtonM {}, new LabelM {})
```

Inheritance increases brevity somewhat,

```
class WithSwing[M] extends Swing[M] {
  class UseSite(btn1 : ButtonM, btn2 : ButtonM, lbl1 : LabelM)
}

// Usage ...
val ws = new WithSwing[String]
import ws._
new ws.UseSite(new ButtonM {}, new ButtonM {}, new LabelM {})
```

Answer (score 3):

One might imagine something like

```
import Swing[M]#_
```

to bring all the type members of type `Swing[M]` into scope, but this doesn't exist (`import` expects a value, not a type). For practical purposes, how about a type alias to reduce boiler-plate,

```
type S = Swing[M]
val b: S#Button = ... // Shorter than Swing[M]#Button
```